# How to add linking lines for stacked 100% bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, stacked-chart

I'd like to add linking lines for stacked 100%  bar chart. As did in the following picture.

[image]

Here is part of my ggplot2 code. But I don't know how to make data and use geom_line()/geom_abline()/geom_hline to add linking lines.

```
  pctdata <- mtcars  %>% 
  group_by(am) %>% 
  count(cyl) %>% 
  mutate(ratio=n/sum(n))

ggplot(pctdata, aes(x = as.factor(am),  y=ratio, fill = as.factor(cyl)))+
    geom_bar(position="fill", stat = "identity", width = 0.5) +
        geom_text(aes(y=ratio,label=scales::percent(ratio)), position = position_fill(vjust=0.5),color="white") + scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format())+ 
  coord_flip() + 
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Thanks for the tips.
I've almost finished it.

Here is my code for reference.

```
pctdata <- mtcars  %>% 
    group_by(am) %>% 
    count(cyl) %>% 
    mutate(ratio=n/sum(n))

linedata = data.frame(x1 = rep(0,4), x2 = rep(1,4),y1 = c(0,0.158, 0.369,1), y2 = c(0, 0.615, 0.846, 1))

ggplot()+
   geom_segment(data = linedata, mapping = aes(x = x1 +.25, xend = x2 -0.25, y=y1,yend = y2), linetype = 3) +
   geom_bar(pctdata, mapping =aes(x = am,  y=ratio, fill = cyl), position=position_fill( reverse = TRUE), stat = "identity", width = 0.5) + 
   geom_text(pctdata, mapping =aes(x = am, y=ratio, label= scales::percent(ratio)), position = position_fill(vjust=0.5),color="white") + 
   scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format()) +
   scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0, 1)) +
   labs(x = NULL, y = "Percent (%)") +
   coord_flip() +
   theme_classic()
```

[See the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLI6t.jpg)

Comment: Why the pictures did show in the post? Only urls for pictures.